# Android Market Publishing Multiple apk's

Tags: android, google-play, publishing

I have developed three different versions(as different projects) of an app(large,normal,small). How can I upload them as a single app with multiple apk's. Do I need to change package names? How about Keystore? Do I need to use same keystore or different keystores for different versions. And what about version number? Do the names of apk's matter?

Comment: I would say its actually **Bad idea** to release multiple apk of same app only for the reason of large/normal/small resolution. Instead i would suggest to launch a single app which is compatible with every devices.

Comment: Yeah, but i have a lot of images. app size is getting huge with three type of images.

Comment: More over its ready to upload, i cant change it now

Comment: But still its bad idea because it will more harder to manage multiple app/apks in future if any changes or more features needs to be added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rules for multiple APKs see the [rules](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html#Rules)

**All APKs you publish for the same application must have the same package name and be signed with the same certificate key.**

see also other rules as well ......

To publish multiple APKs for the same application, you must enable Advanced mode in your application's APK files tab (as discussed in the previous section). Once in advanced mode, you can upload, activate, then publish multiple APKs for the same application.

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/07/multiple-apk-support-in-android-market.html

Comment: Thanks. Can you answer my other questions about package names, keystores and apk names?

Comment: can i use same keystore for different packages?