# Publishing one Android app with different versions for external enterprise customers

Tags: android, google-play

My goal is to distribute different release versions of the same app to different enterprise customers (based on business licensing). i.e. Different customers have paid for version X or Y of our one app, and we need to be able to install those different versions of the app at different customers, if they buy new devices, for example.

SO posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491403/publishing-multiple-versions-of-one-app-on-google-market) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11167241/android-market-publishing-multiple-apks) are actually about graphics resource delivery or file size.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39834959/multiple-versions-of-app-in-google-play-store) post is close, but essentially deals with different app resources for the same app version, rather than different app versions for different people.

There are delivery options such as sending an APK via email or hosting the APK on a company website, but these require customers to enable trusting unknown sources, which cheapens the experience.

The Google delivery options include:

1. Google Play Public apps
2. Private apps via Google Play ([here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6145139?hl=en) and [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en)), including their Enterprise Mobility Management (EMM)
3. [This](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6145139?hl=en) option also describes publishing internal apps for another organization

Option 1 would require a different package name per version, and wouldn't allow for upgrades.

Option 2 Seems to suggest that you can only deploy to users in your G-Suite

Option 3 Seems to require that the target customer uses G-suite for their mobile management, and then making any bug fixes to a particular released version would require updating each target customer's private enterprise app.

None of these options is attractive. Is there another option that I've missed?

Comment: What not only one version but with a log in system? Each user is linked to a paid version and, based on that, he has only access to the specifics parts/options of the app?

Comment: The servers are typically hosted in customer VPNs, so not accessible over the general internet, and don't always have outward internet access either